# ubuntu error: opening the cache, permissions denied

Tags: permissions, cache

I get this error every day on my ubuntu screen:

[image: Image of error notification]

I am a new user and unable to resolve this. Could any one tell me what is it and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you recently performed an `apt update` without using `sudo`? If you open the Terminal and `sudo apt update`, do you still see the error?

Comment: when i run sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade, it goes but next day same error notification repeat again.

Comment: Actually not next day, next time when i on the laptop.

Comment: Do `full-upgrade` instead of upgrade.

Comment: Still error is showing today.